# HTML page height not taking full height of screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to create a page with a sidebar section along and a main content section as shown below, the main section height does not take the full height of the page and I just can't figure out how to get it to do that:

Here is a [link](http://dandoquote.iwobi.image-plus.co.uk/payment-test) if you'd like to see it for yourself.

[image]

Here is the relevant section of my view file:

```
<div class="header">
                <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}"> <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/new-logo.png" class="img-responsive logo" alt="Responsive image"></a>
    </div>


      <div class="row" style="margin-right:0px">

            <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
              <h3>Request a quote</h3>

              <p>To obtain a quotation simply take two minutes to complete our form. Our policies are all underwritten by AVIVA Insurance and arranged through Residentsline Limited. </p>

               <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/residentsline-insurance-brokers.png" class="img-responsive residents-line-logo-sidebar img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">
            </div>

            <!-- This is the main section  -->
            <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main get-a-quote-page">

            <div class="top-bar" style="display:none">
              <h3>Request a quote</h3>

              <p>To obtain a quotation simply take two minutes to complete our form. Our policies are all underwritten by AVIVA Insurance and arranged through Residentsline Limited. </p>

               <img src="{{ URL::to('/') }}/images/residentsline-insurance-brokers.png" class="img-responsive residents-line-logo-sidebar img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image">

            </div>  

            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="col-md-8 payment-thankyou">
                <h1 style="text-align:center">Thank you</h1>
               <p class="thankyou-text" style="text-align:center">Thank you for your kind instructions, please find below your letter confirming cover along with your Statement of Fact and Invoice. The documents are also being emailed to you.</p>
               <br/>
               <p class="thankyou-text" style="text-align:center">Upon receipt of your payment we will issue your Policy Documents.</p>

            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

I have applied the following css to the `.main` class:

```
.main {
    background: #e6edf5;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: 45px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The `height:100%` just doesn't seem to work here, any ideas how I can get the height of the main section (blue background) to take cover the entire screen?

Comment: [Try this link](http://callmenick.com/post/css-equal-height-columns-three-different-ways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `vh` instead of `%`

`vh` = [viewport height %](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

```
.main {
   background: #e6edf5;
   margin-right: 0px;
   padding-right: 0px;
   padding-top: 45px;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: `height: 100vh` did the trick, although not sure how compatible this is with different browsers, works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the .main div either a hard height in pixels as opposed to percentage or you could add height: 100vh; vh = viewport height, which means the div needs to take up the height of the browser.

Also the div is not taking up the height of the browser because it does not have enough content to fill it up and make it longer.

Comment: I just noticed on your webpage that there is a scrollbar at the bottom and you can scroll left/right which shouldn't happen, after seeing your code through inspect element I suggest you remove the margin-left you have applied to the .main div as that is what is causing the scroll.